# Show a representation is faithful

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-presentation

I am working with the dihedral group $D_{8}$ of order $8$, given by the presentation
$$D_{8} = \left\langle a,b: a^{4}=b^{2}=1,\: b^{-1} ab = a^{-1}\right\rangle.$$

I am trying to find if this representation is faithful or not: $\rho: D_{8} \to GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ satisfying
$$\rho(a)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
    -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \quad \text { and } \quad \rho(b)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1
\end{array}\right).$$

Is there a better way to do this rather than check if each individual element maps to the identity? With $8$ elements, it's not too hard, but this technique quickly becomes more tedious with larger groups.

Comment: $\rho(a)$ has order $2$ whereas $a$ has order $4$

Comment: Okay, so the reason that it isn't faithful is because $a^4$ = 1 while $\rho(a)^2$ = 1?

Comment: Those two matrices commute with each other, so the image of the representation is abelian (and in fact has order $4$).

Comment: I don't see why that changes whether or not it's faithful.

Comment: @Clyde: well, do you know that $D_8$ either 1) is not abelian or 2) has order $8$? Either of those is enough to conclude that $\rho$ must have nontrivial kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, $\rho(a)$ has order $2$ while $a$ has order $4$. This means that $a^4 = 1$ and $\rho(a)^2 = 1$; because $\rho$ is a homomorphism, we get that $\rho(a^2) = 1$. Assume that $\rho$ is injective, then $a^4 = a^2 = 1$. This contradicts the minimality of $4$ as the order of $a$. Therefore, $\rho$ is not injective and thus not faithful.